# Convert arraylist loop with java 8 foreach

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Need to convert for loop (Java 6) to foreach (Java 8)

```
 List<CustomFormAttributeLite> custFormAttrLiteList = ArrayList ... ;
Map<String,Map<Long,Long>> customNameId = new HashMap<String, Map<Long,Long>>();
Map<Long,Long> custNameAndType = null;

for(CustomFormAttributeLite customFormAttributeLite:custFormAttrLiteList) {

    custNameAndType = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
    custNameAndType.put(customFormAttributeLite.getId(), customFormAttributeLite.getFieldType());

    customNameId.put(customFormAttributeLite.getName(), custNameAndType);
}
```

I am trying something like that.. But not sure how to do that

```
custFormAttrLiteList.forEach((customFormAttributeLite)->
                custNameAndType = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
                custNameAndType.put(customFormAttributeLite.getId(), customFormAttributeLite.getFieldType());

                customNameId.put(customFormAttributeLite.getName(), custNameAndType);
            );
```

Comment: Those are lambdas you're working with, that's what you should be looking for, you pretty much got the for each right.

Comment: Should be using `groupingBy` ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`Collectors#groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) for this purpose. First group by the name field then group by id and fieldType.

```
List<CustomFormAttributeLite> custFormAttrLiteList = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String,Map<Long,Long>> customNameId = custFormAttrLiteList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustomFormAttributeLite::getName,
                         Collectors.toMap(CustomFormAttributeLite::getId, CustomFormAttributeLite::getFieldType)));
```

If the names are not unique, the result won't be the same as you expect so in that case we need to use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and use the `mergeFunction` to retain only the second non-unique entry:

```
Map<String,Map<Long,Long>> customNameIdNonUnique = custFormAttrLiteList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomFormAttributeLite::getName, //key mapper function
                     (obj) -> {Map<Long,Long> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put(obj.getId(), obj.getFieldType()); return map;}, //value mapper function
                     (key1, key2)-> key2)); //retaining only the second entry
```

As a test I've used the following dataset, to test both these solutions:

```
CustomFormAttributeLite c1 = new CustomFormAttributeLite("foo", 123L, 123L);
CustomFormAttributeLite c2 = new CustomFormAttributeLite("foo", 124L, 125L);
CustomFormAttributeLite c3 = new CustomFormAttributeLite("bar", 125L, 126L);
CustomFormAttributeLite c4 = new CustomFormAttributeLite("bar", 125L, 126L);
```

The second solution yielded the output:

```
{bar={125=126}, foo={124=125}}
```

Comment: You can also use `obj -> Collections.singletonMap(obj.getId(), obj.getFieldType())` as value mapper function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only final variables inside for-each lambda expression. So try like this:

```
final Map<String,Map<Long,Long>> customNameId = new HashMap<String, Map<Long,Long>>();
custFormAttrLiteList.forEach((customFormAttributeLite)-> {
                Map<Long,Long> custNameAndType = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
                custNameAndType.put(customFormAttributeLite.getId(), customFormAttributeLite.getFieldType());

                customNameId.put(customFormAttributeLite.getName(), custNameAndType);
            });
```

Comment: +1, I would add that it is not required to explicitly mark them as `final`, just that they be effectively final, which means the lambda cannot assign a new value to the variable.

Comment: Yes that's fine now

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to **avoid mutating state of a collection** in `forEach`. Collect the data using `.collect(...)` instead.

First create a method (either *static* or *dynamic*) for mapping a `CustomFormAttributeLite` to `Map<Long,Long>`:

```
Map<Long,Long> mapToNameAndType(CustomFormAttributeLite attribute){
    Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(attribute.getId(), attribute.getFieldType());
    return map;
}
```

Then you can simply collect the data into a new `Map` using `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, Long>> customNameId = 
    custFormAttrLiteList.stream()                                                                         
                        .collect(toMap(CustomFormAttributeLite::getName,this::mapToNameAndType));
```

Comment: `list.forEach` != `list.stream().forEach`, nothing bad in mutating using the first, which is what the OP does.